how can i solve attributeerror in python?
I was working on a datascience project got stuck
I used append function but its not working.
here its giving an error :
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'
def recommend(name, cosine_similarities = cosine_similarities):
    # Create a list to put top restaurants
    recommend_restaurant = []
    
    # Find the index of the hotel entered
    idx = indices[indices == name].index[0]
    
    # Find the restaurants with a similar cosine-sim value and order them from bigges number
    score_series = pd.Series(cosine_similarities[idx]).sort_values(ascending=False)
    
    # Extract top 30 restaurant indexes with a similar cosine-sim value
    top30_indexes = list(score_series.iloc[0:31].index)
    
    # Names of the top 30 restaurants
    for each in top30_indexes:
        recommend_restaurant.append(list(df_percent.index)[each])
    
    # Creating the new data set to show similar restaurants
    df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['cuisines', 'Mean Rating', 'cost'])
    
    # Create the top 30 similar restaurants with some of their columns
    for each in recommend_restaurant:
        df_new = df_new.concat(pd.DataFrame(df_percent[['cuisines','Mean Rating', 'cost']][df_percent.index == each].sample()))
    
    # Drop the same named restaurants and sort only the top 10 by the highest rating
    df_new = df_new.drop_duplicates(subset=['cuisines','Mean Rating', 'cost'], keep=False)
    df_new = df_new.sort_values(by='Mean Rating', ascending=False).head(10)
    
    print('TOP %s RESTAURANTS LIKE %s WITH SIMILAR REVIEWS: ' % (str(len(df_new)), name))
    
    return df_new


It never has. It's a method on the module not on the dataframe object

concat is function of pandas not method of pandas.DataFrame, you should feed it with sequence (e.g. list) of DataFrames to concat, simple examplt
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3],'y':[4,5,6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[40,50],'y':[70,90]})
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index=True)
print(df3)

gives output
    x   y
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6
3  40  70
4  50  90

Note: ignore_index=True is used to avoid duplicate indices.

Maybe you can try this
df_new = pd.concat([df_new, pd.DataFrame(df_percent[['cuisines','Mean Rating', 'cost']][df_percent.index == each].sample())])

